# How do i fix an implicit conversion for a ruby json code

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I'm trying to save a json file with already inputed data with the code snippet below:

```
def read_rentals
  return [] unless File.exist?('rentals.json')

  rentals_json = JSON.parse(File.read('rentals.json'))
  rentals_json.map do |rental|
    Rental.new(rental['date'], @person[rental['person_index']], @books[rental['book_index']])
  end
end
```

but I get the error message:
`block in read_rentals': no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError)`

it stopped my script from running. robocop `Rental.new` line above as the error case.

Answer (score 0):

The JWT.encode method expects a hash of claims. You should simply get the first value of the array and put that in as a parameter. There is no other way around. This is simply the current state of the ruby-jwt implementation.

Comment: But I'm adding it directly as a map(which does an iterative addition) of all rental input already in the rentals.json. Can you please elaborate more? i need all data in the file not just one

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

in my rentals.json, my `person_index` was set as null. i changed it to an integer, and the script was working

```
[
  {
    "date": "04/23",
    "book_index": 0,
    "person_index": 0
  }
]
```